# How to pass For-Each current item into Azure Spark Notebook

Tags: foreach, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

Spent a few hours attempting to pass the @item() from a for-each activity into an Azure Spark notebook as a string.  So that others do not have to struggle with this I will provide the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use dynamic content @concat(item()) [image: Screen Shot] as the value of your parameter.

This converts the object into a JSON string which you can then parse in your notebook.  I think I was just tired of fighting the problem and could not see this simple solution.